# CVS remote tagging

Tags: cvs

I want to remotely tag a CVS archive for a given date and time, this seems to be supported by the -D parameter but I can only find examples of the format to use for dates:

```
cvs -d :pserver:server:/repo rtag -D 20081121 module
```

Dates seem to take the format of YYYYMMDD but I can't seem to work out the format for times, YYYYMMDDHHMM gets the following error:

```
cvs [rtag aborted]: Can't parse date/time: 200811210000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [ISO 8601 date format](http://www.saqqara.demon.co.uk/datefmt.htm) (CCYY-MM-DD), for example 2008-11-21.
Add quotes if it contains spaces, for example: "2008-11-21 00:00".

There are other allowed date formats. See http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/, page 67 of the pdf version.